# How to draw overlay window winform apps c#

Tags: c#, winforms

my request is suppose i have two sdi form. one sdi main form has button and when user click on that button then a overlay semi transparent window will appear and cover the main sdi form and as well as another sdi will come on top of the over lay window.

### here is my overlay window code

```
namespace CSRAssistant
{
    public partial class MaskedDialog : Form
    {
        static MaskedDialog mask;
        static Form frmContainer;

        private Form dialog;
        private UserControl ucDialog;

        private MaskedDialog(Form parent, Form dialog)
        {
            this.dialog = dialog;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.Opacity = 0.50;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            this.Size = parent.ClientSize;
            this.Location = parent.PointToScreen(System.Drawing.Point.Empty);
            parent.Move += AdjustPosition;
            parent.SizeChanged += AdjustPosition;
        }

        private MaskedDialog(Form parent, UserControl ucDialog)
        {
            this.ucDialog = ucDialog;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.Opacity = 0.50;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            this.Size = parent.ClientSize;
            this.Location = parent.PointToScreen(System.Drawing.Point.Empty);
            parent.Move += AdjustPosition;
            parent.SizeChanged += AdjustPosition;
        }

        private void AdjustPosition(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form parent = sender as Form;
            this.Location = parent.PointToScreen(System.Drawing.Point.Empty);
            this.ClientSize = parent.ClientSize;
        }

        //
        public static DialogResult ShowDialog(Form parent, Form dialog)
        {
            mask = new MaskedDialog(parent, dialog);
            dialog.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            mask.MdiParent = parent.MdiParent;
            mask.Show();
            DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog(mask);
            mask.Close();
            return result;
        }

        public static DialogResult ShowDialog(Form parent, UserControl dialog)
        {
            mask = new MaskedDialog(parent, dialog);
            frmContainer = new Form();
            frmContainer.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            frmContainer.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            frmContainer.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            frmContainer.Height = dialog.Height;
            frmContainer.Width = dialog.Width;

            frmContainer.Controls.Add(dialog);
            mask.MdiParent = parent.MdiParent;
            mask.Show();
            DialogResult result = frmContainer.ShowDialog(mask);
            frmContainer.Close();
            mask.Close();
            return result;
        }

        public static void CloseDialog()
        {
            if (frmContainer != null)
            {
                frmContainer.Close();
            }
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // MaskedDialog
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Name = "MaskedDialog";
            this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.MaskedDialog_FormClosing);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.MaskedDialog_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        private void MaskedDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void MaskedDialog_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

this way i am calling my overlay when user click on main sdi button.

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show();
MaskedDialog.ShowDialog(this, f2);
f2.Dispose();
f2 = null;
```

when i am running the code and `MaskedDialog.ShowDialog(this, f2);` is calling then i am getting a error....the error message is **Form that is already visible cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Set the form's visible property to false before calling showDialog.**

so i am not being able to understand where i am making the mistake. anyone can help me to fix the problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this wrong - call `mask.ShowDialog()`, not `mask.Show()` and `dialog.ShowDialog()`. The error message is pretty clear - you can't `ShowDialog` a form that's already visible - and that's exactly what you're doing in `dialog.ShowDialog(mask);`.

Or, in a way that probably more closely shows what you want to do, when calling `MaskedDialog.ShowDialog`, do this:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
MaskedDialog.ShowDialog(this, f2);
```

In other words - don't show the form you're going to `ShowDialog`. It's going to be made visible by the `ShowDialog` call.

Comment: should i write mask.ShowDialog() & dialog.ShowDialog() ?

Comment: @Mou You just have to understand that nothing executes after the ShowDialog call until the dialog closes, so the answer would usually be "no" :)